# @Incoming not running multithreaded on Quarkus application connecting to RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

**Some background**

We are running a fairly simple application that handles subscriptions and are running into the limits of the external service. The solution is that we are introducing a queue and throttle the consumers of this queue to optimize the throughput.

For this we are using a `Quarkus` (2.7.5.Final) implementation and using `quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-rabbitmq` connector provided by `quarkus.io`

**Simplified implementation**

```
rabbitmq-host=localhost
rabbitmq-port=5672
rabbitmq-username=guest
rabbitmq-password=guest

mp.messaging.incoming.subscriptions-in.connector=smallrye-rabbitmq
mp.messaging.incoming.subscriptions-in.queue.name=subscriptions
```

```
@Incoming("subscriptions-in")
public CompletionStage<Void> consume(Message<JsonObject> message) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return message.ack();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return message.nack(e);
    } 
}
```

**The problem**

This only uses one worker thread and therefore the jobs are handles 1 by 1, ideally this application picks up as many jobs as there are worker threads available (in parallel), how can I make this work?

**I tried**

```
@Incoming("subscriptions-in")
@Blocking
```

Didn't change anything

```
@Incoming("subscriptions-in")
@NonBlocking
```

Didn't change anything

```
@Incoming("subscriptions-in")
@Blocking(ordered = false)
```

This made it split of into different worker threads, but ?detached? the job from the queue, so none of the messages got ack'd or nack'd

```
@Incoming("subscriptions-in-1")
..
@Incoming("subscriptions-in-2")
..
@Incoming("subscriptions-in-3")
```

These different channels seem to all work on the same worker thread (which is picked on startup)

The only way I currently see is to slim down the application and run one consumer thread each and just run 50 in parallel in kubernetes. This feels wrong and I can't believe there is no way to multithread at least some of the consuming.

**Question**

I am hopeful that I am missing a simple solution or am missing the concept of this RabbitMQ connector.

- Is there anyway to get the @Incoming consumption to run in parallel?
- Or is there a way in this Java implementation to increase the prefetch count? If so I can multithread them myself

Comment: Can you open an issue? The rabbitmq connector is experimental, and I do not believe it supports multi-threads yet.